# How to use wxWidgets rendering loop using wxPaintEvent?

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, windows-xp, wxwidgets

I am trying to grab images using MIL library and I wanted to render the image to glCanvas window using OpenGL. However, the problem is my

```
    OnPaint( wxPaintEvent &event)
```

method is not running in a loop to show the pictures. I have put code in this method to grab images using MIL and set them as textures before displaying them. So, if **wxPaintEvent** is running itself in a loop, why don't I see an image sequence, like a video? When I check with default texture without using MIL, its working. So, basically, I'm just setting the textures!

I'm not using interprocess and mutexes, could this be a problem? Or, do I need to be more careful about timing of this **event**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Paint events are usually only issued if the window has been marked as "invalid" or "dirty", and is deemed to require a redraw. If you want to play an animation, either mark the window as subject your redraw yourself ( [wxWindow::Refresh](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/stable/wx_wxwindow.html#wxwindowrefresh) ). Or, the preferred method, register an idle event handler and perform OpenGL operations from there: http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Making_a_render_loop

Comment: Thank you! I will try to use idle event handler! But could you briefly explain what you ment by: "mark the window as subject your redraw yourself ( wxWindow::Refresh )"?

Comment: @Zizzou: Every window has a buffer attached in which the areas that require a redraw are kept track off; historically all windows share the very same framebuffer and the windowing system has to keep track of ther layering and which parts of a window are/become visible. So if some part of a window gets exposed the windowing system marks this part as "dirty/invalidated" and calls the window drawing handler, so that it "fixes" the affected part be redrawing it. By calling "wxWindow::Refresh" a signal is sent to the windowing system, that the whole window has become dirty and should be redrawn.